# Convert date from string iOS swift 5

Tags: swift, date-formatting

I am trying to convert 'Wed Oct 14 2020 05:31:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)' this date string into swift Date using following code

```
let DATE_FORMAT = "E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss z"

let isoDate = "Wed Oct 14 2020 05:31:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = DATE_FORMAT
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")

print(dateFormatter.date(from: isoDate))
```

It is returning nil, I think I am not specifying date format correctly, any help will be much appreciated

Comment: the timezone representation is not cleary in a disegtable format for the parser, you'd need to be get rid of the noise around the timezone... eg. `"GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"` -> `"+0000"` and that would do the job for you

Comment: Or you can use a NSDataDetector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Unicode LDML date format](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) doesn't support `GMT+0000` (however it supports `GMT+00:00`) nor strings like `(Coordinated Universal Time)`

A possible solution is to remove the non-standard parts from the string with Regular Expression

```
let dateFormat = "E MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"

let isoDate = "Wed Oct 14 2020 05:31:08 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)"

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.dateFormat = dateFormat
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
let trimmedIsoDate = isoDate.replacingOccurrences(of: "GMT([+-]\\d{4})\\s\\([^)]+\\)", with: "$1", options: .regularExpression)
print(dateFormatter.date(from: trimmedIsoDate))
```

The pattern captures the `+0000` part and replaces everything from GMT to the end with the captured time zone

Comment: Thanks @vadian, for your help :)